# Just installed Ubuntu 12.04. When booting, all I get is a black screen with cursor

Tags: 12.04, boot, screen, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Installation appears to go fine.  After rebooting, I get my motherboard loading screens, but when it comes time for Ubuntu to boot, I just get a black screen with a blinking white underscore in the top-left - same as I got when waiting for the install CD to load, except it lasts forever.  The only keypress it seems to recognize is ctrl+alt+del, which reboots.  Letters don't register, function keys w/ or w/o modifiers do nothing.

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 twice and got the same error.

The first time, I installed it as the only OS, and had it take up the whole disk.

The second time, I installed Windows 7 first, then Ubuntu by specifying custom partitions.  After this install, it would boot straight to Windows without showing grub.  I used EasyBCD to add the Ubuntu installation to grub, and this got grub to show, and let me select it, but it led back to the same error described up top.

I've had Linux Mint 11 and 12 installed on this PC, but was unable to get previous versions of Ubuntu to install (always had errors while installing, not after).

Hardware:
Intel Core i7-2600K Sandy Bridge 3.4GHz (3.8GHz Turbo Boost) LGA 1155
ASUS SABERTOOTH P67 (REV 3.0) LGA 1155 Intel P67 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard
EVGA 01G-P3-1371-TR GeForce GTX 460 (Fermi)
CORSAIR Vengeance 16GB (4 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800)
Western Digital RE4 WD5003ABYX 500GB 7200 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive